# Reading/writing a properties file with lua

Tags: io, lua

In java i'm used to using the built in classes for reading and writing properties files but something similar doesn't exist for lua.

Whats the simplest way to save a name and a value to file and then get the value back using the name?

Comment: It all depends what you really want. Lua is table-centered. Consider reading http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization to see the design decisions you have to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simplest* way would be something like this:

```
local name, value = "abc", 123
local f = io.open("outfile", "w")
f:write("return {" .. name .. " = " .. value .. "}")
f:close()

---

local t = dofile("outfile")
print( t[name] )
--> 123
```

This works, but isn't very secure as `dofile()` just executes whatever Lua code it finds in the file.  If the file returns a table full of your saved values as it does here then it works just great, but someone could easily edit this file to contain `os.execute("sudo rm -rf /")` or other such delightful fun.

It's possible to make this more robust with judicious use of `setfenv()` and `debug.sethook()`, but if you want to do it properly you should use one of the many serialisation libraries for Lua, a selection of which can be found [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this example,
https://flicsdb.com/read-properties-file-in-lua/
It explains how to read properties file and also ignore white space or #